Get, Delete, Upload Winforms Files c# Onedrive
I found several examples on the Microsoft site but I was unable to do the following, populate a datagridview with a list of files and folders on OneDrive, and be able to delete or upload files. I have already signed up on Azure with the various keys, but I was unable to formulate a working code on Winforms C#. Net 8.
this my code:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using Microsoft.Kiota.Abstractions.Authentication;

namespace TestAPiOnedrive
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private const string clientId = "my-client-id";
        private const string tenantId = "my-tenant-id"; 
        private const string clientSecret = "my-client-secret"; 
        private async Task ListOneDriveFilesAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                var confidentialClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                    .Create(clientId)
                    .WithTenantId(tenantId)
                    .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                    .Build();

                string[] scopes = { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
                var authResult = await confidentialClient.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
                var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((requestMessage) =>
                {
                    requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResult.AccessToken);
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }));

                var driveItems = await graphClient.Me.Drive.Root.Children.Request().GetAsync();
                dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
                foreach (var item in driveItems)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(item.Name, item.File != null ? item.File.MimeType : "Cartella");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Errore: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 2;
            dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Nome File";
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Tipo";
        }

        private async Task BTNGetFile_ClickAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await ListOneDriveFilesAsync();

        }
    }

}

I am getting an error on:
        var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((requestMessage) =>

Severity Code Description Project File Line Status Delete
Error (active) CS0246 The type or namespace name 'DelegateAuthenticationProvider' was not found. A using directive or assembly reference is probably missing. TestAPiOnedrive C:\Users\Davide\Downloads\TestAPiOnedrive\TestAPiOnedrive\Form1.cs 28
another error here:
var driveItems = await graphClient.Me.Drive.Root.Children.Request().GetAsync();

Severity Code Description Project File Line Status Delete
Error (Active) CS1061 'DriveRequestBuilder' does not contain a definition of 'Root' and no accessible extension method 'Root' was found that takes a first argument of type 'DriveRequestBuilder'. A using directive or assembly reference is probably missing. TestAPiOnedrive C:\Users\Davide\Downloads\TestAPiOnedrive\TestAPiOnedrive\Form1.cs 33

Leaving aside WinForms - have you managed to make an API call at all? If you can get the API working within a console app to start with, then integrating that in WinForms should be feasible.

No unfortunately I was not able to call the APIs even in the console app. I found some code examples as I said, but I have errors with non-existent properties. I used some examples with Microsoft Graph but without success. Apparently they are code examples for previous versions of this library

So please give details of exactly what library you're trying to use, what resources you've found, etc. The WinForms aspect isn't nearly as important as "how to access the API" here.

attached code that I use for winforms, but console makes little difference

Except that because you've chosen to make it a WinForms app instead of a console app, it's much harder than it needs to be for anyone to reproduce. There's no need for a data grid view etc at all - a lot of the code in your sample is unnecessary. Please read https://jonskeet.uk/links/stack-hints and edit your question accordingly. Next, have you looked at https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/tree/main/docs? I'd expect that example to be up-to-date.

thank you all so much for the help, after modifying and making the code working I had an API authentication problem, the problem was due to the fact that the tenant is not necessary to specify it for onedrive personal, but differently for onedrive business. Here is a working code to populate a datagridview with file list and with web browser authentication.
(you must first register your app for free on azure with the 3 permissions present in the code: User.Read, Files.ReadWrite, Files.Read):
  private string GetTokenFilePath()
  {
      return Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "token.txt");
  }

  private void SaveToken(string token)
  {
      File.WriteAllText(GetTokenFilePath(), token);
  }

  private string LoadToken()
  {
      if (File.Exists(GetTokenFilePath()))
      {
          return File.ReadAllText(GetTokenFilePath());
      }
      return null;
  }



  private IPublicClientApplication _pca;
  private string[] _scopes = { "https://graph.microsoft.com/Files.Read", "https://graph.microsoft.com/Files.ReadWrite", "https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read" };
  private string _clientId = "my-clientID";
  private string _authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common"; // Authority per account Microsoft personali

  public Form1()
  {
      InitializeComponent();

      _pca = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(_clientId)
          .WithAuthority(_authority)
          .WithRedirectUri("http://localhost") // Assicurati che sia configurato correttamente su Azure
          .WithLogging((level, message, containsPii) =>
          {
              // Abilita il logging per diagnosticare eventuali problemi
              Console.WriteLine($"MSAL: {level} {message}");
          }, LogLevel.Verbose, enablePiiLogging: false, enableDefaultPlatformLogging: true)
          .Build();
  }

  private async Task<string> SignInAndGetTokenAsync()
  {
      // Prova a caricare il token esistente
      string token = LoadToken();
      if (token != null)
      {
          return token;
      }

      try
      {
          var result = await _pca.AcquireTokenInteractive(_scopes).ExecuteAsync();

          if (result != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.AccessToken))
          {
              token = result.AccessToken;
              // Salva il token per usi futuri
              SaveToken(token);
              return token;
          }
          else
          {
              MessageBox.Show("Token non ricevuto. Verifica il processo di autenticazione.");
              return null;
          }
      }
      catch (MsalException ex)
      {
          MessageBox.Show($"Errore durante l'autenticazione: {ex.Message}");
          return null;
      }
  }


  private async Task GetOneDriveDataAsync(string token)
  {
      using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
      {
          client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

          HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children");

          if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
          {
              string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

              try
              {
                  var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(content);

                  // Accedi alla proprietà "value" che contiene l'array dei file
                  var filesArray = jsonObject["value"] as JArray;

                  if (filesArray != null)
                  {
                      // Configura le colonne della DataGridView
                      dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
                      dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Name", "Name");
                      dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Id", "ID");
                      dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Size", "Size");

                      // Popola la DataGridView
                      dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();

                      foreach (var file in filesArray)
                      {
                          var name = file["name"]?.ToString();
                          var id = file["id"]?.ToString();
                          var size = file["size"]?.ToString() ?? "N/A";

                          dataGridView1.Rows.Add(name, id, size);
                      }
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      MessageBox.Show("Nessun file trovato nella risposta.");
                  }
              }
              catch (JsonReaderException ex)
              {
                  MessageBox.Show($"Errore durante la deserializzazione della risposta JSON: {ex.Message}");
              }
          }
          else
          {
              string errorContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
              MessageBox.Show($"Errore durante la chiamata all'API di OneDrive: {response.StatusCode}\n{errorContent}");
          }
      }
  }




  private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      string token = await SignInAndGetTokenAsync();
      if (token != null)
      {
          await GetOneDriveDataAsync(token); utilizzando il token
      }
  }

using:
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

